# Wrong number of bind variables complication in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, binding, conditional-statements

I have a table in which I get all the listings of the table through the Ruby Find Function.

```
conditions = [Project.in_used_projects(:alias => "projects") + " AND name LIKE ? test"]
projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

But the moment I add "AND name LIKE ? test", I get wrong number of bind variables. The function **Project.in_used_projects** returns the value: **projects.status = 2**

I can't just change the Project.in_used_projects to project.status = 2 because the value is different for every project. 
The error I get is:

```
wrong number of bind variables (0 for 1) in: (projects.status = 2) AND name LIKE ? test
```

I know to bind variables the format needs to be: (Parameter, Parameter, Variable, Variable) but I need it to be (Paramters, Variable, Paramter, Variable)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you **do** have the wrong number of bind variables. You have 1 question mark, but 0 bind variables. Assuming you are looking for a name with "test" in it somewhere, you need to put "test" as a bind variable, or hard code it, like this (0 bind variables, 0 slots):

```
[Project.in_used_projects(:alias => "projects") + " AND name LIKE '%test%'"]
```

Or like this (1 bind variable, 1 slot):

```
[Project.in_used_projects(:alias => "projects") + " AND name LIKE ?", '%test%']
```

Comment: haha oh my. it seems you were indeed correct. I cannot believe I made such a newbie mistake. And all this while I was searching for another solutions. Sigh. Thanks again. I guess I really need to get to bed.

Comment: What about instead of using a string, I use a variable instead? so it would be " AND name LIKE ?," "%#{query}%". All of this is the view btw. is it possible to pass a param into a view?

Comment: @JayG, Yes, you can use a variable like that. That's why you would use use a "?". If you knew the word was "test" ahead of time, you can safely just hard code it as in my first example. But if you don't know, it is not safe to hard code it, so you should use a param as in the second example (but, as you say, replacing `'%test%'` with `"%#{query}%"`.

Comment: You can pass a variable into a view easily. The controller and view share instance variables. So Just set an instance variable in the controller, like `@something = 'asdf'`. Then in the view you can access it as `@something`. But I think you are going about this incorrectly. Finders that invoke sql like the above should definitely not be in the view. Best case, you put them in a model. If that isn't possible, you put them in a controller. But you should never put them in a view.

Comment: The view also has access to the same `params` hash that the controller has, as well as `request`, `response`, `cookies`, `session`, `controller`, etc... Nearly the same environment as the controller. But again, you should keep all your logic out of the view, and almost all the logic out of controllers. The vast majority of code logic belongs in models.